# Powerpoint Macros: Column(unknown member) error at Columns.Width Formatting code

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm new to coding directly in the Powerpoint Macros interface, while learning formatting I hit a roadblock.

Slide 10 of Presentation has a 5 by 7 table. I would like to adjust the width of column 3.

The code I use is:

```
Sub FormatTables()

Dim s As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim ThisRow As Integer

Set s = ActivePresentation.Slides(10)
s.Select

For Each oSh In s.Shapes
            If oSh.HasTable Then
                Set oTbl = oSh.Table
                oTbl.Columns(1).Width = 72 * 0.5
                oTbl.Columns(2).Width = 72 * 0.5
                oTbl.Columns(3).Width = 72 * 0.5
                
                For lRow = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
                    For lCol = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count
                        With oTbl.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
                            .Font.Name = "Georgia"
                            .Font.Size = 8
                        End With
                    Next
                Next
            End If
Next
```

The error I get is: "Columns (unknown member): Integer out of range. 3 is not the valid range of 1 to 2.

Also, the width of columns 1 and 2 are adjusting successfully, but the macro hits the error at the line of code of Column 3.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: I would remove the s.Select statement, as it's not necessary, but your code works as expected here, even with that statement in place. Is there anything unusual about the table?  Merged rows/columns or ???

Comment: "3 is not in the valid range of 1 to 2" points to merged cells. These are always a problem in VBA.

Comment: Thank you for this! The table I have was copied from an excel file, it looks right but powerpoint seems to detect differently. I've resulted to creating a new table and the macro works just fine.